# Nodejs send data in gzip using zlib

Tags: node.js, gzip

I tried to send the text in gzip, but I don't know how. In the [examples](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html#zlib_examples) the code uses fs, but I don't want to send a text file, just a string.

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'});

    const text = "Hello World!";
    res.end(text);

}).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're half way there. I can heartily agree that the documentation isn't quite up to snuff on how to do this;

```js
const zlib = require('zlib');
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'});

    const text = "Hello World!";
    const buf = new Buffer(text, 'utf-8');   // Choose encoding for the string.
    zlib.gzip(buf, function (_, result) {  // The callback will give you the 
        res.end(result);                     // result, so just send it.
    });
}).listen(80);
```

A simplification would be not to use the `Buffer`;

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'});

    const text = "Hello World!";
    zlib.gzip(text, function (_, result) {  // The callback will give you the 
      res.end(result);                     // result, so just send it.
    });
}).listen(80);
```

...and it seems to send UTF-8 by default. However, I personally prefer to walk on the safe side when there is no default behavior that makes more sense than others and I can't immediately confirm it with documentation.

Similarly, in case you need to pass a JSON object instead:

```
const data = {'hello':'swateek!'}

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'});
const buf = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data), 'utf-8');
zlib.gzip(buf, function (_, result) {
    res.end(result);
});
```

Comment: What does the value of `_` represent in the callback? I'm thinking maybe an error, but can't find it documented...

Comment: @cprcrack It's just an unused parameter to the callback. `_` is valid as a variable/parameter name and I use it as a marker that makes it quite obvious (to me) that it's not used.

Comment: I get the idea, but still would like to know why the callback caller is using that parameter and whether it may sometimes be used/useful.

Comment: @cprcrack The in this case ignored parameter is `error`, that is, if gzip fails to compress the buffer, you'll get the error passed back there. All zlib [convenience methods](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_convenience_methods) pass (error, result) back as parameters to the callback.

Comment: As a heads up, you should use `Buffer.from` when converting a string to a buffer instead of `new Buffer`. `new Buffer` has been deprecated. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding

Comment: I had to convert a JSON object to buffer, so this is how I did it:

var data = {'hello':'swateek!'}

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'});
 var buf = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data), 'utf-8');
 zlib.gzip(buf, function (_, result) {  // The callback will give you the result, so just send it.
  res.end(result);
});